# How to get thread pid on linux from C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux

So in `htop` I see a really bad thread consuming 70% from one of the cores.

[image]

And I want to map my application logic to threads pid executing it say

```
Network read pid 22882
Network write pid 22874
```

So I wonder how to get pid of executing thread from it?

To create a thread I use `boost::thread`

Comment: use `gettid` to get `tid` of thead

Answer (score 4):

use `getpid()` to get `pid`. use `gettid()` to get `tid`(thread id).

> getpid() returns the process ID of the calling process
>
> gettid() returns the caller's thread ID (TID). In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by getpid(2)). In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID.

Answer (score 2):

A threaded linux process has

(1)  an OS pid shared by all threads within the process - use `getpid`

(2)  each thread within the process has its own OS thread id - use `gettid`

(3) a pthreads thread id used internally by pthreads to identify threads when making various pthread related calls.

The value you are interested in with `htop` is (2) so you need to use `gettid` to display it.

There is currently no call wrapper for `gettid` so you have to access it via `syscall`.  The code below is an example from the `gettid` man page.  Note that in this program the pid and tid will be the same because it is a single threaded program.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t tid;

    tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [getpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) function from the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the thread identifier from the threads using `pthread_self()` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_self.html) ... however since a process can have more than one threads, all the threads will report the same pid (using http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpid) ...

Comment: If a thread has same pid as invoker how they are displayed different in `htop`?

Comment: 1. You can see the htop source at: https://github.com/ramen/htop/blob/master/htop.c and 2. highly possibly what you see there are not threads, but child processes since they have a unique PID (possibly created with fork)